# Animating UIImageView frame by frame

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, frame

I have an idea about how to add animated UIImageView using frame by frame method BUT my question is about How to animate UIImageView **ALREADY** added on view controller storyboard as  IBOutlet UIImageView .

what will be changed at this peace of code ?!

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark5.png"],nil];

    myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];

   [myAnimatedView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 131, 125)];

    myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;

    myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25;

    myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [myAnimatedView startAnimating];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:myAnimatedView];
```

I want to animate this image like that over my viewController

http://imageshack.us/a/img717/3051/bookmarkl.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's even easier. First, add in .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *iV;
```

After, connect this outlet to the actual UIImageView on your storyboard. Change your code:

```
iV.animationImages = myImages;
iV.animationDuration = 0.25;
iV.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[iV startAnimating];
```

And that's all. Hope this helped

p.s. And yes, don't forget iV = nil; in - (void)viewDidUnload method

UPD: added

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
```

After startAnimating call, and obviously added animationDone method:

```
- (void)animationDone {
    [iV stopAnimating];
    [iV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark5.png"]];
}
```

Comment: thank you .. it works great BUT how can I stop animation at last frame image ?! it returns again to the first frame image .

Comment: this works for me .. Is there any other way ?
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bookmark5.png"];
    [myAnimatedView setImage:image];

Comment: I think [myAnimatedView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark5.png"]] is fine

Comment: Unfortunately .. It works from the second time to animate not from the first time .. I don not know why ?! any Help ??

Comment: It works great now . I appreciate your efforts very much . many thanks ."voting postponed when I reach reputation of 15 "

Answer (score 0):

Well it will be pretty much the same. You dont need to allocate your image view `[[UIImageView alloc] init]` nor do you need to add it to the viewController. The rest is the same.